# Add cities to a map (ggplot2)

Tags: r, ggplot2, polygons, ggmap

I'm struggling with ggplot for days. I want to built a map with the different areas in different colors, and add the names of the cities on it. I manage to plot the map with the areas colored in a different fashion with the following code:

```
#require
library(plyr)
library(dplyr)
library(rgdal)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggmap)

#open data
data = read.table("region.txt", header=T, sep="\t", quote="", dec=".")
#open shapefile
mapa <-  readOGR(dsn=".",layer="DEPARTEMENT")

#merge dataframe/shapefile
mapa@data$id <- rownames(mapa@data)
mapa@data   <- join(mapa@data, data, by="ID_GEOFLA")
mapa.df     <- fortify(mapa)
mapa.df     <- join(mapa.df,mapa@data, by="id")
plotData <- join(mapa.df, data)

#plot
mapfr <- ggplot(plotData) + 
aes(long,lat,group=group,fill=area) + 
geom_polygon() +
geom_path(color="NA") +
coord_fixed() +
theme_nothing(legend = TRUE)
```

I then open the dataset containing the names and the long/lat of the cities I want to plot on the created map :

```
#opendata
points = read.table("cities.txt", header=T, sep="\t", quote="", dec=".") 
#add points on the map    
mapfr + 
geom_point(data = points, aes(x = long, y = lat), color = "black", size = 1)
```

But my points are totally out of the map. Nevertheless, the coordinates are correct. Any idea what I should change to get my points correctly plotted? I know there is a way to do it with the "maps" package, but I'd like to use ggplot.

My datasets are available [here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/jwt2jg29ah8clhv/AAB7DBn0dRIu6tvSK4ykzNapa?dl=0)

Comment: Look at `plotData` - the `long` and `lat` are not correct. They look to be inflated by some order of magnitude -- e.g., row #1 has long = 885735.5 and lat = 6676883.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I just figured out that the problem came from the values in the shapefile. I ll close the question...

Comment: just in case somebody struggles with the same issue. Instead of looking for another shapefile with the coordinates in another format, it is possible to convert the actual coordinates with the `spTransform` command from the `rgdal` package - add this line in the code right after importing the shapefile 

`mapa <- spTransform(mapa, CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84"))`

and coordinates will be given in long/lat

Comment: Great, please post this as your answer and accept it so that others can benefit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just in case somebody struggles with the same issue. Instead of looking for another shapefile with the coordinates in another format, it is possible to convert the actual coordinates with the `spTransform`command from the `rgdal package` - add this line in the code right after importing the shapefile `mapa <- spTransform(mapa, CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84"))` and coordinates will be given in long/lat